# Android RecyclerView - animate item elevation on touch

Tags: android, animation, transition, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I would like to achieve a transition like the one shown in this video (from a Google course): https://youtu.be/iYN5mM0JN9M?t=22s

In words: when an item of a RecyclerView is clicked, it "comes out" of the list (elevation change) and then expands into a full screen view.

Any hints on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

May be you can change item hight to parent size and play scale animation after that?